# Why does my DD4T project find more than one controller?

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, dd4t

I created a DD4T project from scratch including ASP.NET MVC 4 website, I copied all files (lib, conf & license included) from DD4T template but when I deploy the solution there is a problem related to the Routes;

```
The request for 'Page' found the following correspondents : 
DD4T.Web.Mvc.PageController
MyProject.Web.DD4T.PageController
```

I don't understand why I should need to define a namespace in routes.MapRoutes() while it's not required in the DD4T template [here](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/).

It looks like Unity is responsible of this, but why ? Here is my web.config :

```
<unity>
<typeAliases>
  <!-- Lifetime manager types -->
  <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
  <typeAlias alias="external" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
  <!-- define aliases for interfaces -->
  <typeAlias alias="IPageProvider" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IPageProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="IComponentProvider" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IComponentProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="IBinaryProvider" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IBinaryProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="ILinkProvider" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.ILinkProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="ITaxonomyProvider" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.ITaxonomyProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="IComponentPresentationRenderer" type="DD4T.Mvc.Html.IComponentPresentationRenderer, DD4T.Mvc" />
  <typeAlias alias="IPageController" type="DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.IPageController, DD4T.Mvc" />
  <typeAlias alias="IComponentController" type="DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.IComponentController, DD4T.Mvc" />
  <typeAlias alias="IPageFactory" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Factories.IPageFactory, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="IComponentFactory" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Factories.IComponentFactory, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <typeAlias alias="ILinkFactory" type="DD4T.ContentModel.Factories.ILinkFactory, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
  <!-- 
    Define aliases for implementations 
    This is where we determine which classes to use for our implementations!
  -->
  <typeAlias alias="PageProvider" type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
  <typeAlias alias="ComponentProvider" type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionComponentProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
  <typeAlias alias="BinaryProvider" type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionBinaryProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
  <typeAlias alias="LinkProvider" type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionLinkProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
  <typeAlias alias="TaxonomyProvider" type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionTaxonomyProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
  <typeAlias alias="ComponentPresentationRenderer" type="DD4T.Mvc.Html.DefaultComponentPresentationRenderer, DD4T.Mvc" />
  <typeAlias alias="PageController" type="Test.Web.DD4T.PageController, Test.Web.DD4T" />
  <typeAlias alias="ComponentController" type="Test.Web.DD4T.ComponentController, Test.Web.DD4T" />
  <typeAlias alias="PageFactory" type="DD4T.Factories.PageFactory, DD4T.Factories" />
  <typeAlias alias="ComponentFactory" type="DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory, DD4T.Factories" />
  <typeAlias alias="LinkFactory" type="DD4T.Factories.LinkFactory, DD4T.Factories" />
</typeAliases>
<!-- Unity Configuration -->
<containers>
  <container name="main">
    <types>
      <!-- map the implementations to the interfaces -->
      <type type="IPageProvider" mapTo="PageProvider">
        <!--          <lifetime type="singleton" /> -->
        <property name="PublicationId" type="int" value="0" />
      </type>
      <type type="IPageFactory" mapTo="PageFactory">
        <property name="PageProvider" dependencyType="IPageProvider" />
        <property name="ComponentFactory" dependencyType="IComponentFactory" />
        <property name="LinkFactory" dependencyType="ILinkFactory" />
      </type>
      <type type="ILinkProvider" mapTo="LinkProvider" />
      <type type="ILinkFactory" mapTo="LinkFactory">
        <property name="LinkProvider" dependencyType="ILinkProvider" />
      </type>
      <type type="IPageController" mapTo="PageController">
        <property name="PageFactory" dependencyType="IPageFactory" />
        <property name="ComponentPresentationRenderer" dependencyType="IComponentPresentationRenderer" />
      </type>
      <type type="IComponentProvider" mapTo="ComponentProvider">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
      </type>
      <type type="IComponentFactory" mapTo="ComponentFactory">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <property name="ComponentProvider" dependencyType="IComponentProvider" />
      </type>
      <type type="IComponentController" mapTo="ComponentController">
        <property name="ComponentFactory" dependencyType="IComponentFactory" />
      </type>
      <type type="IComponentPresentationRenderer" mapTo="ComponentPresentationRenderer">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
      </type>
    </types>
  </container>
</containers>
```

Comment: isn't that configured in your dependency resolver? for the sample website that is Unity, see the `<unity>` section in the [Web.config](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/Example/Sample.Web/Sample.Web.Site.Corporate/Web.config#162)

Comment: Yes it is, I don't understand why I have all these problems with Unity, I almost copy-paste the web.config file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity wasn't working because I forgot tridion dlls